# rspec hooks(before and after) is not working

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec

Before hook is not working in the below code and i m using rvm 2.6.3

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec'

describe "sample" do

  puts "Inside code"
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  @driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
  sleep 5


 before(:each) do
   puts "Inside before"
   @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
   @driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
   sleep 5

 end
end
```

Comment: Please describe what the expected behavior is, what the actual behavior is, and include any error messages or stacktraces illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `before` is not running because you have no *examples* - these are built with the `it` command:

```
describe "sample" do
  before(:each) do
    puts "Inside before"
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    @driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
    sleep 5
  end

  it 'does a thing' do
    puts "Inside code"
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    @driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
    sleep 5
  end
end
```

*Edit*

To prove that this works, I took these steps:

1. Make new folder
2. cd in folder and run `rspec --init`
3. Make new file `spec/sample_spec.rb` with content:

   ```
   describe "sample" do
     before(:each) do
       puts "Inside before"
     end

     it 'does a thing' do
       puts "Inside code"
     end
   end
   ```
4. Run it with `rspec`

I am using rspec version 3.8, though it should work with other versions as well

Comment: I have tried but it is not working. Can you please suggest any other work around for this? Or else is there any configuration issues?

Comment: @ArunKumarGKumaraswamy when you say "its not working" ... what specifically is happening?

Comment: the code within before(:each) block is not getting executed

Comment: @ArunKumarGKumaraswamy see the edit to my answer for minimal steps to reproduce. I tested it and it does work, we would need more info about your configuration to figure out why it was not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I done with that. But now while executibng i am getting an error "No SDK specified". But i have congifured RVM2.6.3 in the project settings. Please help on this.

Comment: @ArunKumarGKumaraswamy I'm figuring you're using RubyMine or some other IDE - I have no experience with this. I just run my Ruby code from the terminal.

Comment: Ya I am using Intellij. Thanks for your response. I am also trying from my side. If you get any idea regarding this please share here.